# If Statement is not setting the value specified

Tags: javascript

Asking before I pull my hair out.

The below code is not working. As in, it is not setting the value of the **numPeople** variable to 1 if nothing is entered in that input field. I've coded it no differently then other peoples code I've seen.

```
 if (numPeople === "" || numPeople <= 1) {
    numPeople = 1;
      }
```

It is declared as follows:

```
 const numPeople = document.getElementById('numOfpeople').value;
```

Finally the whole code is:

```
//function that calculates the tip
function calculateTip() {

    //define the variables
    const amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;

    const serviceQual = document.getElementById('serviceQual').value;
    const numPeople = document.getElementById('numOfpeople').value;

    const output = document.getElementById('outputP');

    //validation
    if (amount == '') {
        alert('Please Enter a Number');
        return;
   } 

   if (numPeople === "" || numPeople <= 1) {
    numPeople = 1;
      } 

    //calculation
    var tipTotal = (amount * 0.15 * serviceQual) / numPeople;

    //ui element


    output.innerHTML = tipTotal;

}


//function that calls the tip function
document.getElementById('enter').addEventListener('click', function() {

    calculateTip();

});
```

Comment: What does `document.getElementById('numOfpeople').value;` return if there is no value, did you check that first? Then you would just add a check for that too.

Comment: I am sure there is an error message in your console that you are ignoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because you can't reassign a constant, try:

```
let numPeople = document.getElementById('numOfpeople').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value to a constant variable so use

```
let numPeople = document.getElementById('numOfpeople').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`CONST` type should not be overrided. You are trying to override the `numPeople`  which is a `const`. You can try using `let` or `var` instead.

According to official [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared.

```
let numPeople = document.getElementById('numOfpeople').value;
if (numPeople === "" || numPeople <= 1) {
    numPeople = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying change value of `const` which is not allowed. Either use `var` or `let` keyword.

Check below example.

```js
function getValue() {
  var numPeople = document.getElementById('numOfpeople').value;
  alert("value is " + numPeople)
  if (numPeople === "" || numPeople <= 0) {
    numPeople = 1;
  }
  alert("after value is " + numPeople)
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input id="numOfpeople">
  <button onclick="getValue()">Get Value</button>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```